# How can I soften the 2016 Toyota Tacoma SR5 bumpy ride?

Tags: toyota, suspension, shock-absorber, tacoma

I just purchased a 2016 Toyota Tacoma SR5 and it's a bit bumpy. I feel everything on the road. Any way to soften that? It's relatively new (10k miles), so I'm wondering if it'll soften in time?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the ride will soften over time as the springs start to weaken. If the ride is bad enough, then you can replace the shocks so the suspension absorbs more road impact. Trucks are set up to ride firm, so the ride you feel is by design. You can also purchase tires that provide a more comfortable ride. Trucks have hard tires (to carry load and reduce wear), so a softer tire will help. Also, if you have low profile tires then your ride will be harsh. The tire's sidewall absorbs a lot bumps, so make sure you have more tire and less rim. Checkout tacomaworld.com sometime for more info from other Taco owners.

Comment: Welcome to the Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair stack! Thanks for the contribution! :)